# How to make matplotlib markers colorblind-friendly in a simple way?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, accessibility

Currently I'm using command

```
plt.errorbar(X,Y,yerr=myYerr, fmt="o", alpha=0.5,capsize=4)
```

and I get default marker colours:

[image]

But what should I do to force matplotlib to be more colorblind-friendly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [1] you can use the predefined colorblind style. It should be as simple as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('tableau-colorblind10')
```

[1] https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_2.2.html#new-style-colorblind-friendly-color-cycle

Check out the last image from this link as well:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html

Comment: Is there a way to make this a default using matplotlibrc?

Comment: @nedlrichards use a rc-file https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html